# Can't load website on iframe tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, iframe, hyperlink

I am trying to let my iframe tag load a webpage for a give time
HTML:

```
<div id="banner">
         
<iframe src="" id="adsm">

          

       
 </iframe>
         
 </div>
<Button onclick="view()" id="major">watch</button>
```

The javascript:

```
function view(){
var presenttime=11;
var nextmine=8;
if(presenttime>=nextmine){
      //give a src to the adsm watch section
      //start setting for the countdown
      var timeLeft = 30;
      var timerId = setInterval(countdown,1000);
      function countdown(){
    var value=document.getElementById("count-down");
      document.getElementById("major").onclick="";
       if(timeLeft == -1){
         clearTimeout(timerId);
         document.getElementById("adsm").src="";
         document.getElementById("banner").innerHTML="please try later";
       }
       else{
      var link="https://doomdefender.com/e9k6bqg3y?key=7089140f45b4fcfdb51fb18ec1ead1cc";
  document.getElementById("adsm").src=link;
         document.getElementById("adsm").style.display="block";
         timeLeft--;
      value.innerHTML = timeLeft + ' seconds remaining';
         
       }
        
      }
    }
    else{
      document.getElementById("adsm").style.display="none";
         document.getElementById("banner").innerHTML="please try again later";
    }
}
```

At the end I it doesn't even display anything, I created another project with and tried a similar function and it worked please someone should run the code for me and tell me what's wrong

Comment: is button not Button, that may be your error